# The documents of RPC API has been out of date?

Tags: rpc

I want to provide some RPC interfaces for web to interact with my own contract. I want to use the way like

> curl  http://localhost:8888/v1/chain/push_transaction -X POST -d '{"ref_block_num":"100","ref_block_prefix":"137469861","expiration":"2017-09-25T06:28:49","scope":["initb","initc"],"actions":[{"code":"currency","type":"transfer","recipients":["initb","initc"],"authorization":[{"account":"initb","permission":"active"}],"data":"000000000041934b000000008041934be803000000000000"}],"signatures":[],"authorizations":[]}'

in the link

> https://eosio.github.io/eos/group__eosiorpc.html#v1chainpushtransaction

However it's out of date ? where could i find a correct one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think they updated the code somewhere. What I usually do is to copy what we have from `eosjs` (checking their repo and/or using chrome inspection and looking at the network tab). For now, with DAWN-v4.0.0, we have this structure for the `push_transaction`:

```
  {
    "signatures": [
      "EOSKZ4pTehVfqs92wujRp34qRAvUjKJrUyufZfJDo9fdBLzhieyfUSUJpKz1Z12rxh1gTQZ4BcWvKourzxCLb2fMsvN898KSn"
    ],
    "compression": "none",
    "context_free_data": [],
    "transaction": {
      "region": 0,
      "ref_block_num": "32697",
      "ref_block_prefix": "32649",
      "expiration": "2018-09-25T06:28:49",
      "max_net_usage_words": 0,
      "max_kcpu_usage": 0,
      "delay_sec": 0,
      "context_free_actions": [],
      "actions": [
        {
          "account": "eoseco",
          "name": "transfer",
          "authorization": [
            {
              "actor": "eoseco",
              "permission": "active"
            }
          ],
          "data": "0000000050a430550000000000003ab60a000000000000000045434f0000000000"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your excellent answer. that's what i want.

Comment: Do you know how to get the signatures": [     "EOSKZ4pTehVfqs92wujRp34qRAvUjKJrUyufZfJDo9fdBLzhieyfUSUJpKz1Z12rxh1gTQZ4BcWvKourzxCLb2fMsvN898KSn"  ] manually without using cleos ？could  eosjs sign that?

Comment: Yes you can, my suggestion is to see how Scatter signs transactions because it utilizes eosjs.